# How to get data into every 5 mins in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just wandering, will it be possible to get data into every 5 mins group by name in SQL Server.

Example: I have the following data in a table:

```
id    name          message       datetime
---   --------      -------       --------   
1     David         test 1        2017-12-18 10:00
2     David         test 2        2017-12-18 10:01
3     David         test 3        2017-12-18 10:03
4     Alvin         bluh 1        2017-12-18 10:04
5     Alvin         bluh 2        2017-12-18 10:04
6     David         test 4        2017-12-18 10:06
```

How can I get the result as below in SQL Server?

```
id    name          message       datetime
---   --------      -------       --------   
1     David         test 1        2017-12-18 10:00
2     David         test 2        
3     David         test 3        
4     Alvin         bluh 1        2017-12-18 10:04
5     Alvin         bluh 2        
6     David         test 4        2017-12-18 10:06
```

Comment: `10:00` and `10:04` is not 5 mins apart, why it is still shown ?

Comment: @Squirrel group by name and message

Comment: "test 1" is not the same message as "test 2"

Comment: your `every 5 mins` is fixed (for example 10:00 --> 10:04, 10:05 -> 10:09) or it depends on `datetime` value of the first row? What is the result if the first row is `2017-12-18 09:59`?

Comment: the question is still unclear.. please add more explanation..

Answer (score 1):

Group by Name, and group datetime by 5 mins

```
select  id, name, message, 
        datetime    = case when rn = 1 then datetime end    
from    (
            select  *, rn = row_number() over (partition by name, 
                                dateadd(minute, datediff(minute, 0, datetime) / 5 * 5, 0) 
                               order by datetime)
            from    yourtable t
        ) d
order by id
```

Comment: I need it to be group by name and datetime (within 5 min). Referring to the example above, the script will return 3 set of records for David under date  2017-12-18 10:00 and 1 record for David under date 2017-12-18 10:06

Comment: @JinYong. Edited the query